# How to dispose(destroy) bootstrap 5 modal

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap 5 in a project. I am building a quiz that opens when you click a button. The quiz is shown inside a bootstrap 5 modal component.

My problem is, when you click the close button of the modal and then re-launch it the data from previous quiz round is still there (radio buttons are still checked). I want the close button to destroy the modal and dispose of all previous data. I have tried several methods (separately), as mentioned below:

```
myModal.dispose()
myModal.modal("dispose")
bootstrap.Modal.dispose();
bootstrap.Modal(bootstrap.modal.getInstance(quiz-modal)).dispose
```

Bootstrap 5 has a class called `Modal` and in it there is a `dispose` method, but I am not able to use it.

The name of modal is `myModal` and it is a bootstrap 5 modal. the quiz-modal is reference to html element which is shown as modal.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using bootstrap 5 CDN, do I need to include any import statements in javascript file?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution that seems to work.

```
quizClose.addEventListener("click", () => {
  //reset the forms containing quiz questions
  for (let i = 0; i < totalQuestions.length; i++) {
    totalQuestions[i].reset();
  }
  let myModal = bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(
    document.querySelector(".quiz-modal")
  );
  //remove static backdrop
  myModal.setAttribute("data-bs-backdrop", "false");
  //destroy modal
  myModal.dispose();
});
```

Comment: This (only) clears the modal form values. It doesn't actually clear the modal from the DOM, if that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

*Came here looking for how to dispose the modal completely since it was causing errors when the button used to open the modal was clicked again, instead of allowing the default click event.*

There are effectively two steps to disposing the Modal, the Modal object itself and the Modal DOM element, which subsequently leaves an event listener behind for the `[bs-target]` element, giving an optional third step if using it - but is not needed if the modal is triggered programmatically via JavaScript.

The key takeaway is that the `hidden.bs.modal` event is used to perform the disposal, and a separate `click` event is used for the button to trigger the hide & dispose.

```js
const modalButton = document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle=modal][data-bs-target="#my_modal"]');
const my_modal = document.getElementById('my_modal');
const disposeBtn = document.getElementById('dispose');

if (my_modal) {
  const bsModal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(my_modal);
  let disposeModal = false; // variable placeholder

  if (disposeBtn) {
    // create a click event to hide the modal and flag it for disposal
    disposeBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      disposeModal = true;
      bsModal.hide();
    });
  }

  // bind a hidden event to dispose of the modal after hiding
  my_modal.addEventListener('hidden.bs.modal', () => {
    if (disposeModal) {
      // ensure backdrop is removed
      my_modal.setAttribute('data-bs-backdrop', 'false');

      // destroy the bootstrap.Modal
      bsModal.dispose();

      // remove the modal from the DOM
      my_modal.remove();

      // optional - disable the event listener from retriggering in the DOM
      modalButton.removeAttribute('data-bs-toggle');
      disposeModal = false;

      /* modalButton.click(); // trigger original function */
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<html class="h-100" lang="en" data-bs-theme="dark">

<head>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body class="h-100">
  <div class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <a type="button" href="#" class="btn btn-danger icon-btn" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#my_modal" role="button"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i>Open Modal</a>
  </div>

  <div id="my_modal" class="modal fade" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" aria-modal="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h1 class="modal-title fs-5">Foo Bar</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Hello World</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close Modal</button>
          <button id="dispose" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Dispose Modal</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```